# Fade background color of button on hover css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade the background color of a button from blue to white and fade the font color from white to blue. I checked the other posts on this.

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t533wbuy/1/

I used this fiddle as reference: 
http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/SvjHx/

My issues are:

- I want it to be an A button and not utilize ul > li.
- the font color is not fading to white on hover.

Css

```
.menuitem{
width: 200px;
height:30px;
background-color: #005abb;
font-size:16px;font-family: 'gotham_htfbold';-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.menuitem a{
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
height: auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
z-index: 9999;

}

.menu-item-span{
display: none;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #fff;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
color:#005abb;
z-index: -999;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 }
```

html

  Click here to apply

jquery

```
$(function() {
$(".menuitem").find("class")
.hide() // Finds span hide.
.end() // After find stop.
.hover(function() { // On hover find and fadein then fadeout
$(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
 }, function() {
$(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
});
```

Comment: You can do this with just CSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not go with pure CSS?

```css
a {
  transition: all .4s ease;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
a {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: Hah. You beat me to it!

Comment: you gotta be quick @user1447679 :o)

Comment: OMG this is great, but is there a way to add a custom class to this. I'm not sure how to do that with the double a tags in the code. I originally had a.btnsubmit:link

Comment: I just used nesting instead .blahclass a. Marked as answer!

Answer (score 1):

As @Aaron and @user1447679 mentioned, best practice in this case would be using pure css, but if you say you really want to do it in css, you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to change the `color` and `background-color` of the element with jQuery's `.css()` method:

```
$(function() {
    $("#lnk-1").on('mouseover',function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color','black').css('color','white'); 
    })
    .on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','blue').css('color','black'); 
    });
});
```

Here is a simple demo for how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/t533wbuy/4/